# Finding the marginal distribution

Tags: distributions, multivariate-normal-distribution, marginal-distribution, moment-generating-function

If $p(y) =N(0,\Gamma) $ and if $p(x|y) =N(\Lambda y, \psi I) $where $I$ denotes the identity matrix. Also, we have the conditions:
$\Gamma_{ij} =0$ for $i \neq j$ (diagonal) 
$\Lambda \Lambda^T = I$

What will the distribution of $x$ be? It is clear to me it should be normal and it has been suggested that we can find the mean and variance using the iterated law of expectations.

For example,

$E_X(X) =E_Y[E_{X|Y} [X|Y]] = E_Y[\Lambda y] =0$

The variance is more complicated though:

$Var_X[X] = E_Y[Var_{X|Y} [X|Y]] + Var_Y[E_{X|Y} [X|Y]] = E_Y[\psi I] + Var_Y[\Lambda y] $

I'm not sure how to proceed..I guess the first term is just $\psi I$ but the second is not clear how to use the diagonal covariance $\Gamma$.

Comment: $\newcommand{\Var}{\mathrm{Var}}$For the second term, use the fact (see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2365166/what-is-the-variance-of-a-constant-matrix-times-a-random-vector/2365257#2365257) that if $A$ is a fixed matrix and $z$ is a random vector with covariance matrix $V$, then $\Var(Az)=AVA^T$. So $\Var(\Lambda y) = \Lambda \Gamma \Lambda^T$. And yes, the expectation of $\psi I$ is itself, since this is a constant matrix.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth Thanks. Can we expand this further using the diagonality of $\Gamma$ and the orthonormality of $\Lambda$?Specifically, I tried writing $\Lambda \Gamma \Lambda^T = \Lambda_{ij} \Gamma_{jk} \Lambda_{kl} = \Lambda_{ij} \delta_{jk} \Lambda_{kl} \Gamma_{jj} = \Lambda \Lambda^T  \Gamma_{ii} =  \Gamma_{ii} \text{I} = \text{diag}(\Gamma_{11}, \dots, \Gamma_{nn})$? Therefore we have a distribution $p(x) = N(\Lambda y, \psi I +  \Gamma)$, right?

Comment: You seem to be saying that $\Lambda \Gamma \Lambda^T = \Gamma$, but unfortunately this is not generally true. For example try with $\Gamma =\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 &2\end{bmatrix}$ and $\Lambda =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ -1&1\end{bmatrix}$. You should find that $\Lambda \Gamma \Lambda^T = \frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix} 3& 1\\ 1 &3\end{bmatrix}\neq \Gamma$.

Comment: The $i,j$ entry of $\Lambda \Gamma \Lambda^T$ (for diagonal $\Gamma$) will be equal to $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \Lambda_{ik}\Gamma_{kk}\Lambda_{jk}$.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth Ah ok. That makes sense.However, I am still a little confused. We now have $p(x) = N(0, \psi I + \Lambda \Gamma \Lambda^T)$. This is actually half of a question I'm working on (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/393254/help-with-pca-question) and my thoughts were to show that both distributions are normal with the same expectation and variance. Above we've done one of them but for the other I get $p(x) = N(0, \Lambda \Lambda^T + \psi I)$ (note that for this second distribution we don't have orthogonality of $\Lambda$. Or do you think the question means something else?

Comment: That question seems to be requiring you to show that the set of possible marginals is the same in each model. I think this could occur even if the distributions for $x$ are not the same in both. Plus anyway, the $\Lambda$ in the two models need not be the same, right?

Comment: I think just try and use what you have discovered to show that the set of possible marginals in each model is the same (noting the restrictions on $\Lambda$ and $\Gamma$ where appropriate).

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth So it is a good observation that the parameters $\Lambda, \psi$ don't need to be the same in each case. We have already shown that both marginals are normals centred on the mean and now it is just a case of demonstrating the variances are equivalent. Do you agree that the only remaining bit would be to show that $\Lambda \Gamma \Lambda^T$ can be expressed in the form $AA^T$ for some matrix $A$, right? To do this, we'd want to multiply the $i^{th}$ row of $\Lambda$ by $\sqrt{\Gamma_{ii}}$, right? So if we choose $A$ such that $A_{ij} = \sqrt{\Gamma_{ii}} \Lambda_{ij}$ it's ok?

Comment: I haven't looked too closely at your problem but is $\Lambda$ allowed to be arbitrary in the the one where it doesn't have to be orthogonal? Anyway, you have shown that any $\Lambda \Gamma \Lambda^T$ can be written in the form $AA^T$, which is good, but maybe you should also show (or at least mention, if this is for exams/homework) the reverse, i.e. that any $AA^T$ can be written in the form $\Lambda \Gamma \Lambda^T$ with $\Gamma$ and $\Lambda$ as in the the OP (recall the spectral theorem to help with this).

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth $\Lambda$ is a loading matrix in probabilistic PCA. I believe that allows it to be arbitrary? Also, for this reason, $\Lambda$ is not going to be square since it maps from the latent space to the observable space. Wouldn't this affect the ability to use the spectral theorem?

Comment: OK. I suppose $\Lambda$ and $A$ will typically have more rows than columns? Assume they are both $n\times m$ where $n\ge m$. I will assume for simplicity that $A$ has full column rank $m$. Then $AA^T$ is $n\times n$ with rank $m$ and so has $n-m$ eigenvalues of $0$. Using the spectral theorem, we can write $AA^T = PDP^T$ where $P$ is orthogonal $n\times n$ and $D$ is diagonal $n\times n$ with the last $n-m$ diagonal entries $0$. Then we can set $\Lambda$ to be the first $m$ columns of $P$ (so is $n\times m$) and $\Gamma=\mathrm{diag}(D_{11},\ldots,D_{mm})$. This should give what you want.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth It occurs to me that the distributions in question are in fact multivariate normal as opposed to univariate normal. Do the iterated expectation and variance formulas that we have used still hold? Or is there a different version for covariance? I couldn't find any info about this but I assume what we did is a safe assumption?

Comment: Yes it should be all good. You could try to show these yourself (e.g. try coordinatewise for the law of total expectation and adapt the proof of the law of total variance in Graham Kemp's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1742578/law-of-total-variance-intuition) to the case of vectors). Or, you could perhaps ask your lecturer for a quick proof (if you are doing this as a university course).

Comment: Nope just self learning. Planning to go back to uni and do some statistics next year for a career change. Wouldn't we want a law of total covariance rather than a law of total variance as in the linked to answer?

Comment: $\newcommand{\m}{\boldsymbol{\mu}}$Ah I see. Best of luck with that. And law of total variance should be good enough, because covariance matrix in the vector case is defined analogously to *variance* in the scalar case (the vector case is $\mathrm{Var}(X)=\mathbb{E}\left[(X-\m)(X-\m)^T\right]$ and scalar case is $\mathrm{Var}(X)=\mathbb{E}\left[(X-\mu)^2\right]$).

Answer (score 1):

We will use moment generating functions (mgf's) for the proof. The mgf of a vector random variable $X$ is 
$$ \DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}} 
  M_X(t) = \E e^{t^T X}
$$ and remember that if $X$ is multivariate normal $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\Sigma)$ then $M_X(t)= \exp\{\mu^T t +\frac12 t^T \Sigma t \} $. Now, we have given the conditional distribution of $X \mid Y=y$ is $\mathcal{N}(\Lambda y, \psi I)$ and the marginal distribution of $Y$ is $\mathcal{N}(0,\Gamma)$.

For the mgf we have in general
$$
   M_X(t) =\E e^{t^T X} = \E [\E e^{t^T X}\mid Y=y]= \E M_{X\mid Y=y}(t;y)
$$
This conditional mgf is 
$$
  M_{X\mid Y=y}(t;y) = \exp\{t^T\Lambda y +\frac12 t^T\psi I t\}
$$
and calculating 
$$\begin{gather}
 M_X(t)&=\E_Y M_{X\mid Y=y}(t;y)=\E \exp\{(\Lambda t)^T Y+\frac12 \psi t^T t\} \\ &= \exp\{\frac12 \psi t^T t\}\E \exp\{(\Lambda t)^T Y\} \\
&= \exp\{\frac12 \psi t^T t\} M_Y( \Lambda t) \\
&= \exp\{ \frac12 t^T [\psi I+\Lambda^T \Gamma \Lambda] t\}
\end{gather}
$$
so we can finally conclude that $X$ is marginally $\mathcal{N}(0,\psi I+\Lambda^T \Gamma \Lambda)$.